# Planned self-learning curriculum?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm currently taking a year off between high school and college. I'm working as a junior IT technician, so I'm getting plenty of experience on the hardware side of things. I want to use this year off to also get started on some programming; I have experience in Visual basic from high school courses, but want to further my learning before going to school. Now, obviously I will not be able to become overly proficient in all of these, but these are the languages that I plan on learning over the course of the next few years:

- PHP
- Ruby (on Rails)
- Python
- (Objective) C__ (I'll research my college program and see what C they use, and learn that)
- Java
- Lisp

Will being proficient in these languages give me a good base to work from? I tried to pick a selection of languages that seem to offer good employability, ability to develop on a number of platforms (desktop, web, mobile), and ones that are currently popular and sought-after.

Am I missing anything? Does anyone see anything important that I've missed, things I've picked that are a waste of time, or otherwise?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Yes, being proficient in these seven (as C and Objective C are really very different languages) is a very good base. However, be prepared to spend several years to get proficient in any programming language.

Comment: .. And don't forget all the tools specific for the language that makes you productive. Knowing the syntax and semantics for as many languages as possible is of course good, but I would perhaps concentrate on one language to begin with, and also learn it's many good libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've read the Pragmatic Programmer (a great read)  But there's a section in there on expanding your knowledge portfolio, and they suggest learning one language a year, and I must confess I agree with them.

So I would work out what you want to write, and then pick the language that fulfills the requirements you want.  And as you're going to college, I would also consider what language that the course you're attending is going to be teaching.  I'd most certainly place my effort in to learning that language.

I'd also recommend (assuming they're going to let you use linux) learning a scripting language, such as BASH, and learn to create make or build files in your chosen environment, it's a heck of a lot easier than remembering compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Python is good to start with and then do Java. It would be enough for a starter on my opinion.

If you thought of learing php instead then learn mysql too. And more over you have overall missed the database. :(

Atleast learn my sql or ms sql of your choice.

Comment: I don't generally think of databases as programming languages. I could be wrong, though. Obviously I would need to learn how to use a SQL to develop anything web-based.

Comment: Sql is a scripting language, it can be considered as one.Learning just php wont help you in creating good websites so i added that one too...